# Gatsby crash after updating wordpress post

Tags: gatsby

Gatsby crash after updating wordpress post with this error in development

```
warn  gatsby-source-wordpress  Found a duplicate ID in WordPress - this means you will have fewer nodes in Gatsby than in WordPress. This will need to be resolved in WP
 by identifying and fixing the underlying bug with your WP plugins or custom code.

 ERROR 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseId' of undefined
    at forEach (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/fetch-nodes/fetch-nodes-paginated.js:113:82)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at paginatedWpNodeFetch (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/fetch-nodes/fetch-nodes-paginated.js:95:11)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at getWpActions (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/wp-actions/index.js:27:32)
    at fetchAndRunWpActions (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/wp-actions/index.js:84:21)
    at fetchAndApplyNodeUpdates (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/fetch-node-updates.js:44:36)
    at sourceNodes (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/steps/source-nodes/index.ts:61:5)
    at runSteps (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress/src/utils/run-steps.ts:41:9)
    at runAPI (/Users/my/Desktop/reza/node_modules/gatsby/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:483:16)


 ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress_112003
```

I use gatsby v3.1.3 and wordpress 5.7
and I have limited numer of posts in gatsby-config

```
Post: {
            limit:
              process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`
                ? // Lets just pull 50 posts in development to make it easy on ourselves (aka. faster).
                  20
                : // and we don't actually need more than 5000 in production for this particular site
                  5000,
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .cache and public folders.